# Codeigniter HMVC with ? in url after module

Tags: codeigniter

When I load my url with question mark ? it keeps on showing error page 404.

`http://localhost/project-hmvc/admin/?route=common/dashboard`

Module name is **admin** but need to be able to accept after module name ? it works fine if do not use question mark in url.

> I have tried it with **enable_query_strings true** but does not work. So
>   not going to use it.

**I have set route.**

`$route['admin/?route=common/dashboard'] = 'admin/common/dashboard/index';`

All controllers have there first letter on file name and class uppercase.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

**Question:** How can I make my codeigniter hmvc urls after the module name accept question mark ? with out **enable_query_strings** on config.php

Note: I have tried with `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';` no luck

Codeigniter version 3 running on windows 7 and xampp

```
modules >

modules > admin >

modules > admin > controllers > common

modules > admin > controllers > common > Login.php

modules > admin > controllers > common > Dashboard.php

modules > admin > views > template > login.php

modules > admin > views > template > dashboard.php
```

Comment: can you provide your file structure? you can use http://filestructuregenerator.com for that.

Comment: added module layout as requested

Comment: have you tried modifying your route to this: `$route['admin/?route=(:any)/dashboard'] = 'admin/$1/dashboard/index';`

Comment: No luck hmvc not working with ? in url, the url changes but page not

Comment: HMVC is tricky because you are modifying the way CI was originally designed to work.. Did you edit any system files?

Comment: No have not touched any system files.